# Bootstrap button icon on type input submit not visible

Tags: asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

My hyperlink at the end looks fine. But the first "button", which is an input of type submit, looks bad with Bootstrap. I do not see the image on the button.

Actually, I guess I have to use the submit button with razor but how can I get back my nice button style from Bootstrap? There is no icon visible!

```
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-default fa fa-save" id="saveTeststeps" />
```

Looks good, the icon is visible:

```
<a class="btn btn-default" href="#"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></a>
```

Comment: Have you tried using a `<button>`?

Comment: thanks that worked. Just the buttton is not square anymore. Its more wide than its height.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The icon classes are not intended to be applied alongside other classes, such as those for buttons. Specifically, the icon classes do things like hide text, and also have their own padding, height, line-height, etc. definitions. If you need to use an icon in a button, use the `button` element with an `i` element inside. In general, you should avoid `input`s for buttons, though. HTML should have never allowed that in the first place, as it confuses the purpose of the element: rendering a user input control, which a button is technically not.

Answer (score 4):

Try this :

```
<button class="btn btn-default" type="submit" id="saveTeststeps">
 <i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
</button>
```